# How can I display field validation error messages on formtastic form with :remote => true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have a formtastic form like the following:

```
= semantic_form_for @record, :remote => true, :id => 'my_form', :url => ...
```

Since I'm using :remote => true, I handle the response from the controller in javascript:

```
$('#my_form')
  .bind("ajax:beforeSend", function(evt, xhr, settings){

  })
  .bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
      $('#response').append(xhr.responseText);
  })
  .bind('ajax:complete', function(evt, xhr, status){

  });
```

With :remote => false, my form automatically displays field validation errors resulting from trying to save the record in the controller like so:

```
@record = Record.new(params[:record])
@record.save
```

How do I make the formtastic field validation errors appear with :remote => true, where I'm handling the response myself in javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the formtastic form in a view by itself.

In the controller action that handles the posted form, you can re-"render" the view when the record save fails. When the view is rendered, formtastic will look at the errors field in @record and display the validation errors. If the save succeeds, you can render an empty string to indicate success. (A more complex response scheme is possible depending on what you need.)

```
  def save_record
    if request.xhr?               # form submitted using remote => true
      respond_with do |format|
        format.html do
          if @record.save
            # record saved successfully
            render :text => ""    # indicate success with empty response
          else                    # error saving record; send back form with validation errors marked
            render :template => '/path/to/record_form_view', :layout => false
          end
        end
      end
      return
    end
    #...
  end
```

Then, in the client-side javascript, when the record fails to save, you can replace the existing form with the rendered view passed back from the controller.

```
// reference: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/
function setup_record_form_bindings() {
  $('#record_form_id')
  .bind("ajax:beforeSend", function(evt, xhr, settings){
    var $submitButton = $(this).find('input[name="commit"]');
    $submitButton.get(0).value = "Submitting...";
  })
  .bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){      
      if (xhr.responseText === "") {              // successful save
                                                  // do somethign appropriate here
      } else {                                    // error saving
        $('#record_form_id').remove();            // remove old form, to replace with form in responseText
        $('#record_form_parent_id').append(xhr.responseText);  // should be the newly rendered form (with validation errors shown)
        setup_record_form_bindings();
      }
  })
  .bind('ajax:complete', function(evt, xhr, status){
  });
}
setup_record_form_bindings();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using javascript to post the form, I would suggest to do the validation on client side before submitting any data. Check out https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations

Comment: Thanks a bunch for referring to such a nice gem :-) Works like charm :-) +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Edwards's answer is the best way to do it since it uses Formtastic to add the errors.
In case you (like me) have a very dynamic form that adds fields while being filled out and pulls in images and data based on the values the user fills in, it is not an option though.

I found this Gist which nicely shows how to add the errors the same way that Formtastic would add them: https://gist.github.com/2083155/172ce92caa8d4ee738c32e72e27945e17c909428

Be aware though that this duplicates the logic contained in Formtastic, which is never an optimal solution. If the Formtastic way of showing errors changes at some point in the future, you would have to adjust this code manually.